# Entity Framework ValueGeneratedOnAdd with no requery

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

Say I have EntityFramework Core 2.1.14.

Say I have to integrate data into a legacy MySql database which was created by a self-taught.

Say also that one of the tables in this database has a surrogate key field that is generated on Add.

Say then that I want to use `context.SaveChanges()` to handle the Insert DML generation for me because I want to be lazy and because these tables are messy.

Say finally that I do not want Entity Framework to perform a follow-up query to retrieve this surrogate field; I don't care what it is. I just need it generated on insert.

### How would one call `context.SaveChanges()` with an `Added` object having a property configured as `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` but also instruct Entity Framework to do nothing but generate my `INSERT` ? I don't want it to return the id.

Comment: Say why EF Core 2.x? Do you need just BulkCopy? Search for extensions which can do that. But your EF Core is too old...

Comment: Want you a bulk insert? want you using your new Key in another insert?
Depend what you want... with a bulk insert, you need an extention, but if you want a insert in another table you need a reference object in the relational table. Emplain more please, with example.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comments. I want `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` to have the database generate the surrogate value, but I don't want Entity Framework to worry about retrieving that surrogate when I call `.SaveChanges()`  (In anticipation) I know that there are other ways to accomplish this. That's not the point of the question. The point of the question is: is there a way to provide an option to Entity Framework that instructs it not to attempt to retrieve the surrogate?

Comment: Answer is NO. EF Core do not support fire and forget inserts.